# ¿Cómo hacer para que la función no retorne undefined en la consola?

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for, while

Estoy aprendiendo javascript y entiendo que las funciones deben devolver un valor para que no tiren un "undefined" en consola. El tema es que me gustaría realizar el siguiente código dentro de una función para no tener que ir comentando varias lineas al continuar con los ejercicios.
El código es simple, es contar del 10 al 1 e imprimirlo en consola, fuera de la función funciona (sin tener el acumulador), pero al ponerlo dentro de la función pensé en tener un "acumulador" para devolver ese valor, el tema es que si uso "return" la función se corta y solo devuelve 10, si uso console.log(acumulador) (ese console.log dentro del while) la función cuenta del 10 al 1 pero al final devuelve también "undefined".
La pregunta sería, cómo hacer que la función haga el bucle retornando los valores del 10 al 1 sin que termine imprimiendo "undefined".
Bien de novato la pregunta!!

```
function contarDelDiezAlUno() {
    let contador = 10;
    let acumulador = 0;

    while (contador >= 1) {
        acumulador = contador;
        console.log(acumulador);
        
        contador -= 1;
    }
    
    
}

console.log(contarDelDiezAlUno());
```

Comment: por defecto todas las funciones retornan undefined. Si quieres que retorne algo, tienes que ponerle un return y lo que quieras devolver. Ejemplo `return acumulador`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema nace de un pequeño malentendido:

"Entiendo que las funciones deben devolver un valor para que no tiren un "undefined" en consola".

No necesariamente, hay funciones que devuelven cosas y funciones que no, la tuya es un ejemplo de las que "no", aunque podría no serlo.

Ejemplo de función que no retorna nada:

```
function mostrarMensaje( mensaje ) {
    alert( mensaje );
}
```

Supongamos que no tienes que imprimir en consola la lista de números, sino que tienes que guardarla, entonces usarías un array (**acumulador**) para almacenar los sucesivos valores de contador para al finalizar devolverlo.

```js
function contarDelDiezAlUno() {
    let contador = 10;
    let acumulador = [];  // creamos el array
    acumulador.length = 10;  // determinamops su tamaño
    while( contador >= 1 ) {
           // en cada iteración, guardamos el valor de contador
        acumulador[acumulador.length - contador] = contador;                       
        contador -= 1;
    }    
    return acumulador;
}
console.log( contarDelDiezAlUno() );
```

También puede ocurrir que tengas un return... y no retorne nada, simplemente se usa para finalizar la función.

```
function accederAlSistema( nombre ) {
    if( nombre.estaHabilitado() ) {
        return;
    }
    abrirPuerta();
    entrar();
}
```

Comment: Ahh gracias! Planteaba esto ya que me imaginaba que el día de mañana me podría generar algún problema con un código más complejo!!

Comment: Un placer maestro!.